# 415 error when sending objects and file to the server at once

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, react-hook-form

I want to send file and objects to the server at at once, but I get 415 error.
I use react-hook-form library

**frontend
**

```
const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    }

    const handleFormSubmit = async (e) => {

        const data = [{
            petname: e.petname,
            age: e.age,
            type: e.type,
            weight: e.weight,
            firstmet: e.firstmet
        }];

        const formData = new FormData();

        formData.append("file", e.file[0]);
        formData.append("request", new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], {contentType:"application/json"}))

        console.log(formData)

        await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/pet/petform", formData, {
            headers: headers
        })
            .then((response) => {})
            .catch((error) => {})
    }
```

**backend
**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/petform",
            consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public void save(@RequestPart(value="file", required = false) MultipartFile file,
                     @RequestPart(value="request", required = false) PetDTO petDTO) throws IOException {

    }
```

**error code
**

```
Request failed with status code 415
```

When the parameter was sent to the postman, the spring boot was stamped normally.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsDUn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpV76.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have an array here:

```
        const data = [{
            petname: e.petname,
            age: e.age,
            type: e.type,
            weight: e.weight,
            firstmet: e.firstmet
        }];
```

Should be

```
        const data = {
            petname: e.petname,
            age: e.age,
            type: e.type,
            weight: e.weight,
            firstmet: e.firstmet
        };
```

To match the request